# Legendary sets for increased magic find

Tags: diablo-iii

Are there any sets in this game that focus primararly on magic finding gear much like Tal Rasha's in Diablo II? If so could somone please link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**

I don't know of an easy-to-browse listing of set items, so I can't give you a complete list, but here are a few examples:

**[Tal Rasha's Wrappings](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/tal-rashas-guardianship)** appears in D3, and some of the pieces have increased magic find. The belt, helm, and chest armor all have 15-16% magic find, and all the pieces have random attributes that I believe can be MF as well.

There are also legendary items like the **[Lut Socks](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/lut-socks)** (coughLootSockscough), that offer magic find, gold find, and additional random attributes.

You can browse all items, including sets and legendaries, here: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/

Comment: Lists of all the [craftable sets](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/#type=set), [sets in general](http://www.diablowiki.net/Set_Items), and the [most used sets](http://diablo.somepage.com/popular/items/).